# If checkbox selected add class 'active'

Tags: jquery

I find it easy to usually add a class active in jQuery but this time i am trying to implement it into a piece of code that is connected with google maps.

My snippet code to show and hide markers using jQuery is this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            show(id);
        } else {
            hide(id);
        }
      });
```

example of my input and labels

```
<input type="checkbox" id="school" class="checkbox" /><label for="school">Schools</label>
```

What i want to do is if the checkbox is clicked, add a class to it AND display the marker.

I have tried adding the AND operator in and using  `$(this).addClass('active');` to the code but no luck. Is this possible to implement in this code or will i have to create it from scratch again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get it, but something like this should work:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
    var state = this.checked;
        func  = state ? show : hide;

    func(this.id);
    $(this).toggleClass('active', state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some slight amends i have found a solution:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"] + label').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
```

My google map code was conflicting with the jQuery so this is a separate function below.

Can someone tell me why this has been down voted? Just for next time i ask a question.

Thanks.